# Should "the" be capatalised in this situation?

Tags: capitalization

My friend is starting a blog, and the name she is planning to use for it is based in this structure:

"Becky" the "Foodie".

Should "the" in the name/title be capitalised? Becky The Foodie? Or Becky the Foodie?

Thanks so much!

Comment: She can call her blog bEckY tHE fOOdIe if she wants - it's her blog, and her name to choose. Most traditionalists would prefer the dowdy little function word 'the' to remain uncapitalised, though, so Becky the Foodie would be more likely to be visited by those people. But are those the sort of people she wants visiting?

Comment: @terdon thanks for the link and sorry if I repeated the question.

Comment: @She's a traditionalist! :) She just wanted to make sure since she's going to do some banner/logo designs in photoshop and it'll be a hassle to change the capitalisation. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules of English dictate that "the" should not be capitalized. Depends whether you think it's important to obey those rules or not, really, many people don't.